# Is this an ARMA(1,1) or something else?

Tags: time-series, arma

I have a company, for which I calculated the logarithmic loss (-logarithmic return). Now I want to fit a mean equation to the returns, so I have to think about fitting an ARMA(p,q). I lookt at the acf and pacf and get the following picture:

[image: arma]

This seems not to be a simple AR or MA?
What is this, what should I use?
Data can be found [here](http://uploadeasy.net/upload/wieql.rar).

It would be nice, if you explain me what you do in order to know what process is appropriate.

Comment: Has the data been differenced?

Comment: Post the data and we can take a look at it...

Comment: @toomuchpj no, it has not.

Comment: I uploaded the data, it would be nice, if you explain me what you do in order to know what process is appropriate. So I can understand and follow.

Comment: Doesn't look like the variance is constant.

Comment: @Scortchi ok, so you mean, it is not stationary, what does that imply? Should I not fit an ARMA? Difference or what?

Comment: The mean's not wandering - differencing probably wouldn't be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting of the time series, `plot(logloss,type="l")`, shows the variance is very clearly not constant. It doesn't seem to vary with the mean, suggesting that a transformation won't help. Rather it seems to wax and wane over time. You might want to look into [AutoRegressive Conditional Heteroskedasticity (ARCH) models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity).

[Response to comment: No particular ARMA model's strongly indicated by the ACFs (bear in mind the heteroskedasticity is going to give the distribution fat tails) - try fitting a GARCH to the data as is, & then to residuals from an ARMA(1,1), & compare the results. You've got enough observations so that tests or information criteria will probably suggest a more complex model with 'balancing' MA & AR parameters that doesn't make much difference to the predictions, but it's up to you what's sensible given the context.]

Comment: ok, maybe my question was not detailed enough: I want to fit a mean equation and a volatility equation. So for the mean equation I wanted to use an ARMA(1,1) and then a ARCH or GARCH for the volatility equation. So my question is: Can I use an ARMA(1,1) for the mean equation? I think the unconditional variance has to be stationary, not the conditional variance. Just because of the plot, you cannot say that the unconditional variance is not stationary, since the conditional variance can indeed vary quite strong and still the uncond. variance is still constant. So what do you think?

Comment: well, you say I should first fit an GARCH model and then use the residuals for evaluating. But the problem is, that I do jointly estimation, so I already have to specify the mean equation when fitting the GARCH model?

Comment: By all means estimate ARMA & GARCH parameters jointly - should be more accurate. My point was - fit both a plain GARCH & an ARMA-GARCH & compare the models. I'd suspect, from the plots, that the plain GARCH would be adequate.